# PHP - get certain word from string

Tags: php, string, get, cpu-word

If i have a string like this:

```
$myString = "input/name/something";
```

How can i get the **name** to be echoed? Every string looks like that except that name and something could be different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

so the only thing you know is that :

- it starts after input
- it separated with forward slashes.

>

```
$strArray = explode('/',$myString);
$name = $strArray[1];
$something = $strArray[2];
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$parts = explode('/', $myString);
echo $parts[1];
```

This will split your string at the slashes and return an array of the parts. 
Part 1 is the name.

Comment: Remember to test array items before use: if (isset($parts[1])) echo $parts[1];

Answer (score 4):

If you only need "name"

```
list(, $name, ) = explode('/', $myString);
echo "name is '$name'";
```

If you want all, then

```
list($input, $name, $something) = explode('/', $myString);
```

Answer (score 0):

use the function `explode('/')` to get an array of `array('input', 'name', 'something')`. I'm not sure if you mean you have to detect which element is the one you want, but if it's just the second of three, then use that.