# php - text file, echo password from text file

Tags: php

hi there i'm using a text file as a database the contents of my text file are as follows....

```
SRC ---> M ---> 11/22/1995 ---> myPassword ---> 11/29/2013
```

what i want to do is write a `php` code that searches for `src` and returns the password i am using the following code to search the text file..

```
<?php
$file = 'Database.txt';
$searchfor = 'src';

// the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

// get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
// escape special characters in the query
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
// finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
// search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
   echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
}
else{
   echo "No matches found";
}
?>
```

how can i make it echo the password.... any help would be appreciated... thanks in advance... :) i know using text file as a database isn't secure but still...

Comment: *"how can i make it echo the password"* – Believe me, you don't want to do that.

Comment: Never ever ever ever store a password as plaintext. And what Fred said… I hope that's not your real email address in the code. You need to become a little more paranoid if you are going to connect your computer to the internet.

Comment: haha.... i know..... well... it's not gonna echo the password.... it's gonna do other things.... all i need is it to get the password... sooo i said echo.

Comment: @Floris: it was. not anymore, luckily.

Comment: holy crap... i forgot to remove that.... nah... who cares...

Comment: @briosheje - thanks. But anyone with edit privileges can still see the edit history… maybe a net crawler won't though.

Comment: Could you please write sentences. Second why are you using this strange file format? You could use CSV or something really easy to parse.

Comment: @wumm… wow…. I hadn't noticed… how strange...

Comment: well i'm a wierd person... what can i say..

Comment: *"well... it's not gonna echo the password.... it's gonna do other things"* - So tell us your actual intentions then.

Comment: well if the password is correct it's gonna show a welcome message..

Comment: Just to clarify what others have been saying: If you're working with passwords they should **never be stored as plain text**, even if it's in your database and never shown on screen. The best way to handle passwords is to use a hashing algorithm such as bcrypt immediately when it is first input. Then any subsequent password checks should hash their input and compare the hashes. The original password should kept be in state that even the system administrator cannot recover it. If not, your system is not secure: there have been many cases of hackers publishing password data: don't be one of them

Comment: i know..... i just want to do it coz... well.... i'm learning...

Comment: "I'm learning". We al are - it's a good thing. So from this exercise, learn that **what you are proposing here is NOT RECOMMENDED**. The time to learn good habits is before you acquire bad ones.

Comment: hey... thanks u guys... i found the solution....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just put in this code:

```
$strArray = explode(' ---> ',implode($matches[0]));
$name = $strArray[3];
echo "\n" . $name;
```

after:

```
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
```

tho i took a bit of a help from [PHP - get certain word from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415210/php-get-certain-word-from-string)