# How to get word between particular symbols in string

Tags: php

My source string could be:

example.com or http://example.com or www.example.com or https://example.com or http://www.example.com or https://www.example.com
or

example.abc.com or http://example.abc.com or www.example.abc.com or https://example.abc.com or http://www.example.abc.com or https://www.example.abc.com

I want the result: **example**

How can we do this using php string functions? or in other way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - get certain word from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415210/php-get-certain-word-from-string)

Comment: It is not duplicate, in any way.!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$str = 'http://example.abc.com';
$last = explode("/", $str, 3);

$ans = explode('.',$last[2]);
echo $ans[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.parse-url.php)

```
<?php
    // Real full current URL, this can be useful for a lot of things
    $url = 'http'.((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 's' : '').'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    // Or you can put another url
    $url = 'https://www.example.foo.biz/';
    // Get the host name
    $hostName = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    // Get the first part of the host name
    $host = substr($hostName, 0, strpos($hostName, '.'));

    print_r($url);
    print_r($hostName);
    // Here is what you want
    print_r($host);

?>
```

Comment: your answer is partially correct. please, recheck my post

Comment: Can you explain what is missing ? From what I understood, you just want to get the host name from a URL.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
<?php

$url = "http://www.example.com";

/* Use any of you want.
$url = "https://example.com";
$url = "https://www.example.abc.com";
$url = "https://www.www.example.com"; */

if ($found = strpos($url,'example') !== false) {


  echo "it exists";

}
?>
```

**EDIT:**

So this is what I cam up with now, using [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
$url = "http://www.example.com";

/* Use any of you want.
$url = "https://example.com";
$url = "https://www.example.abc.com";
$url = "https://www.www.example.com"; */

 $exp ='example';
if ($found = strpos($url, $exp) !== false) {

echo $str = substr($url, strpos($url, $exp));  
echo "<br>". "it exists" . "<br>";

$finalword = explode(".", $str);
var_dump($finalword);

}
?>
```

Comment: 'example' word is dynamic, it is not static.

Comment: @SujVan Ahh, give me a second!

Comment: @SujVan Would this be fine now? `;-)`